# Migrating From 2008 R2 Domain Controllers to 2016 Domain Controllers

Tags: domain, domain-controller

I have a client who I recently upgraded from 2003 domain controllers to 2008 R2 domain controllers. The upgrade was successful, but now comes the upgrading 2008 R2 DCs to 2016 Standard. I was wondering if the following steps are correct and if any of the steps will cause an issue if I still have a couple of server 2003 boxes on the network. We will be replacing the few 2003 boxes that we have left ASAP, but they must remain on the domain for the time being.

The steps are as follows:

1. Switch all subnets in AD Sites and Services to same site (consolidating sites)
2. Move 2nd DC from old site to new
3. Delete old site of 2nd DC
4. Raise forest and domain levels to 2008 R2
5. Run ADprep (Do I need to run RODCprep off of the 2008 R2 disc if I did not do so yet, or can I just run the 2016 ADprep right off of the bat?)
6. Migrate FRS to DFSR for SYSVOL and other replication
7. Add new domain controllers
8. Remove old domain controllers
9. Potentially raise the forest and domain levels to match the 2016 server updates

If someone could please let me know if these steps are in the appropriate order, and if there is anything else that I should be aware of.

Thanks!